# How to view a MINIDUMP_USER_STREAM_INFORMATION in a minidump?

Tags: windbg

My program creates a minidump when it gets upset and in the dump we're 'supposedly' creating a user comment stream.  I say supposedly, since I can't verify it.

Can anyone tell me the magic `WinDbg` command to see a comment stream stored inside a `MINIDUMP_USER_STREAM_INFORMATION`?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

dumpchk.exe, in debugging tools folder, will dump all streams of a dump.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 SP1 (Premium) does not show the comment.
Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 (Premium) does also not show the comment.

When opening the dump in WinDbg, it will show the comment almost at the top:

```
Line 1: WinDbg version
Line 2: Copyright
Line 3: Dump name
Line 4: Dump type
Line 5: Dump comment (if available) <--
...
```

I don't know a specific command to extract the comment, so once you cleared the command window, the information is lost.

Just for Google: I came here to find out how to get the comment which was set in WinDbg using the .dump /ma /c command. SysInternals ProcDump also creates .dmp files with comments.